# How to properly use Fluent NHibernate to get the next Sequence in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate / Fluent NHibernate with Oracle and I'm running into an issue.  I've got the following mapping file defined:

```
public OrderMap()
{
    Table("ORDERS");
    Id(x => x.OrderId, "ORDER_ID").GeneratedBy.Sequence("select ORDERS_SQ.nextval from orders");
    Map(x => x.CreatedBy, "CREATED_BY");
    Map(x => x.OrderStatusCd, "ORDER_STATUS_CD");
    Map(x => x.StoreGroupId, "STORE_GROUP_ID");
    Map(x => x.IsActive, "IS_ACTIVE");
    Map(x => x.OrderDate, "ORDER_DATE");
}
```

When I go to run my project I get the following error:

An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory.

If I remove the `.GeneratedBy.Sequence("select ORDERS_SQ.nextval from orders");` line, the application runs but I don't get the next sequence obviously when I save a record.  I've tried doing just `.GeneratedBy.Sequence("ORDERS_SQ");` but I just don't seem to get anything to work right.

Can anyone tell me the proper way to use Fluent NHibernate to get the next available sequence correctly please?

I'm using Fluent NHibernate 1.1 with NHibernate 3.0 Beta.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just specify the name of the sequence:

```
Id(x => x.OrderId).Column("ORDER_ID").GeneratedBy.Sequence("ORDERS_SQ");

// Real working code:
Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Sequence("SEQ_Catalog1");
```

Comment: That is correct but part of my problem was that the data type of the ID field didn't conform to the integral type check that Fluent NHibernate does before creating the sequence.  After changing that everything worked fine.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to return the generated sequence value on insert in one roundtrip?

Comment: @Tsar when NHibernate inserts a record, the Save() method returns the full object with its new ID. In the case of Update(), it'll update the given record.

Comment: Thanks. the problem is my Table has another ID column (GUID) and I had to map this one as Id just to be able to do `GeneratedBy.Sequence`, which isn't available on a normal column map. I guess you can't do what I need to do with Fluent :(